# Which OAuth 2.0 Authentication Flow does the MVC5 use?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, owin, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-oauth

I was going through [this Example](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on). Does this example(for facebook) use Explicit Authentication flow or Implicit Authentication flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at `FacebookAuthenticationHandler.ApplyResponseChallengeAsync()` code in the Katana `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook` namespace, it looks like it always initiates the "Authorisation Code" flow when an HTTP 401 is encountered.

```
        string authorizationEndpoint =
            "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth" +
                "?response_type=code" +
                "&client_id=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(Options.AppId) +
                "&redirect_uri=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(redirectUri) +
                "&scope=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(scope) +
                "&state=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(state);
```

So that's why you have to provide both your clientId and secret in the config. For implicit flow you would not use the secret anywhere.

Comment: Should PKCE be used nowadays or is that an entirely other flow?